# QMovie unexpected argument QBuffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Hi i thought QMovie could take QBuffer?
This is my code.

```
a = QByteArray(img)
b = QBuffer(a)
self.movie = QMovie(b, 'GIF')
```

Comment: I do not know your basic problem, and the normal thing is to use a .qrc, but my answer corresponds to your question, so I think my answer is correct, if so, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour], that's the best way to thank. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the second constructor:

> [QMovie::QMovie(QIODevice *device, const QByteArray &format =
>   QByteArray(), QObject *parent = nullptr)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html#QMovie-1)

and as you see it is expected that the second argument is a `QByteArray` that can be replaced by bytes, so in the next part I show you an example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # load data from
    path = "congratulations.gif"
    file = QtCore.QFile(path)
    if not file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        sys.exit(-1)
    ba = file.readAll()


    buf = QtCore.QBuffer(ba)
    if not buf.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        sys.exit(-1)

    movie = QtGui.QMovie(buf, b"gif")
    w = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    w.setMovie(movie)
    movie.start()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```